# Swift : How to put string in \( )?

Tags: ios, swift

I create a dictionary, and I want to use println() to print dictionary content,

but it doesn't work, and I don't know how to solve it..

Please help...  Thanks

```
var dictionary = ["name":"herny","age":20]
println("name = \(dictionary["name"])");   <--- this doesn't work, compile error because dictionary["name"] in \()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put things with quotes in a `\( )`, you'll need to assign it to a variable:

```
var dictionary = ["name": "henry", "age": "20"];
let name = dictionary["name"];
println("name = \(name)");
```

Comment: it's really trouble and inconvenient...